# NAV tag before the Header in HTML5

Tags: html

Could you please advise if I can you the code below in such order. The thing is that I am going to build a fixed side navigation, and put all the content including the header tag to the right side with float. Thanks.

```
<body>
  <nav>
     <ul>
      <li><a></a></li>
      <li><a></a></li>
      <li><a></a></li>
      <li><a></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
    </header>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `header` and `footer` are simply divs with a different name for convenience.

Comment: So there is no rule to use them in order right? And the code above is absolutely valid? :)

Comment: For semantics, not just convenience. Anyway, there's nothing inherently wrong with putting a nav element pretty much anywhere flow content is expected.

Comment: @EmilGurbanov you can use [This](http://validator.w3.org/check) to validate your html structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gramatically, there is absolutely nothing wrong with placing a `<nav>` element anywhere in the body of an HTML document where flow content is expected (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-nav-element).

Semantically, if the `<nav>` element contains links pertaining to a specific section of the document, then it would be nice to place the navigation itself in that section, optionally in the header of that section. If you see it as the section's table of centents or something like that.

Answer (score -3):

Try using the below format, so you can clearly understand.

```
<body>

    <!--headerStuff-->
    <header>
      <nav>
         <ul>
          <li><a></a></li>
          <li><a></a></li>
          <li><a></a></li>
          <li><a></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="wrapper">
    </div>

    <footer>
       <!--Footer Stuff-->
    </footer>

    </body>
```

Comment: Because your "answer" does not answer the question. You claim to make something clear with your example, but you don't say what and I can't begin to see what it could be.